# Reading space seperated string into array in while loop

Tags: arrays, bash, while-loop, spaces, ifs

I want to read in the owner for a list of files, then compare it to the current owner and output an error if it's not the same.

I have the following, where I've replaced the comparison with a simple echo for simplicity, since it's not the comparison that's going wrong:

```
while IFS=' ' read -ra own; do echo ${own[@]}; done <<< $(stat -c %U file*.*)
```

The stat returns a string list (in this case 3 values), all with my username in this case, but the read just outputs it as a single read and string.

```
<myusername> <myusername> <myusername>
```

Clarification: I mean the the loop processes once only, returning the string with all 3 values, whereas I want 3 iterations of the loop, containing one value each.

I've changed to IFS= and IFS='\t' in case I was misreadint the output of stat in some way, but I get the same behaviour even if I just define a string like "I am here" instead of the stat command, so I'm obviously doing something else wrong.

Oh, I do need it in a one line statement as well, so if that's the problem then I guess I'm a bit screwed.

Comment: `read -a` assigns values in the array `own`. By using `${own[@]}` you get all array elements in one line. This is the correct behavior... What do you expect exactly?

Comment: @oliv I'm assuming I've misunderstood what I should be expecting. I want the values read one at a time, not all in one go. The loop only returns one value, which contains all 3 values, rather than returning 3 values. 

I.e. the loop processes only once, not 3 times as I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get each element of the array, you can loop through the variable `own` with a `for` loop:

```
stat -c %U file*.* | { read -ra own; for i in ${own[@]}; do echo $i; done; }
```

Another way of doing it is:

```
{ read -ra own; for i in ${own[@]}; do echo $i; done; } <<< $(stat -c %U file*.*)
```

Note that you don't need a `while` loop because you get everything on one line.

Comment: I started with that, but that gives the same result: 

    $ while read -r own; do echo ${own}":"; done <<< "here I am, rock me like a hurricane"  ===>  here I am, rock me like a hurricane:

Comment: More specifically, just to make the number of iterations clear: while read -r own; do ((ct++)); echo ${own}":"${ct}; done <<< "here I am" ====> 
 here I am:1

Comment: @urbanespaceman answer updated, but doing string manipulation in pure bash might lead to problem. If you would describe further what you want to do with result of `stat`, it is likely that a text processing tool, like `sed` or `awk` would do the job better.

Comment: That does it! Thanks @oliv. It's only ever intended to read a maximum of about 6 files, and it's going to return an error status if it finds any that aren't owned by the current user (i.e it will compare ${own[@]} with $(whoami) and exit 1 if they're not the same)